# Meteor ReactiveDict MongoDB Find onCreate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to use a mongodb find items and stored in ReactiveDict, but I'm just getting the error:

`{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey...`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Template.body.onCreated(function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('itemFind');
    this.global = new ReactiveDict();
    this.global.set('items',Items.find());
});

Template.body.helpers({
  items(){
  console.log(Template.instance().global.get('items'));
  return Template.instance().global.get('items');
}
});
```

Further, I figured if I added a .fetch() to the original find statement this would be fixed, but apparently not.

I'm new to Meteor, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't put a subscribe on an onCreated?

So where do you put it so the find is only run once?

Comment: Why do you want to use ReactiveDict? `Items.find()` is reactive by default, you just need to put `Items.find()` in you helper

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I put two `Items.find()` into two different helper methods than I'm going to end up with doubled the Items, correct?

Truthfully, I'm trying to understand / delineate between `Session`, `ReactiveVar`, and `ReactiveDict`. I understand the theory, but trying more to understand the their accessibility through the test program Im building.

Comment: You are right about _doubled the Items_, but that can be easily avoided by putting `Items.find()` in another function and use that function whenever you need the items. About `Session` and `ReactiveVar`, `Session` is basically an instance of `ReactiveVar` which is predefined and can be accessed globally

Answer (score 0):

On the `onCreated` the subscription is not ready yet. A good practice is to define your Reactive vars on `onCreated` and assign them on `onRendered`.

In any case, you need to wait for the subscription to be ready. To do so you can use an `autorun()`. The `autorun()` will rerun every time its dependencies are updated.

```
Template.body.onCreated(function() {
  this.global = new ReactiveDict({});
});

Template.body.onRendered(function()
  this.autorun(() => {
  const subs = Meteor.subscribe('itemFind');
    if(subs.ready()) {
      this.global.set('items', Items.find({}));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, but now I'm getting. 

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`

Comment: My bad, you need to use an arrow function in the callback or assign `this` to a variable. `this.global` doesn't exist in the autorun's function scope. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I still can't get this working. I noticed in your first answer you mentioned onRendered. Should ReactiveDict be defined in onCreated and the above moved to onRendered?

_On the onCreated the subscription is not ready yet. A good practice is to define your Reactive vars on onCreated and assign them on onRendered._

Maybe I'm going a little off track here, but I guess I'm trying to establish the best way to do a `.find()`. I get the impression that putting a find in each helper method isn't correct.

Comment: Well, that's what I always do, precisely because everything might not be set up onCreated. Have you tried moving the autorun in onRendered (see edit)?

Comment: Hm. I thought I had tried that, but I must have got it wrong because previously I was getting an error. Now I'm getting no error, but `return Template.instance().global.get('items');` is returning as `undefined`. Is the helper being run before the `subs.ready()`? Perhaps I'm a bit confused about the load order, but seems like the logical conclusion, however now I don't know how to load items as a global.

Comment: Maybe it's the helper that's the problem `return Template.instance().global.get('items');`

Comment: Actually, no. The problem is further up in `onRendered`, as subs.ready() isn't running. I drop a `console.log` in there and it doesn't fire.

Comment: Ok. Back to where I started with: `{{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.`

Comment: Why don't you simply do the `Meteor.subscribe()` `onRendered` and then define your helper as `items() { return Items.find() }`?